# Call of dataframe columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently looking for a solution to call each column of a `data frame` in a `for loop` like this:

```
         V1     V2     V3       V4  V5   V6    V7   V8    V9   V10
Activity dep10  out10  dep500  -5  -15  -90   +45  +20   +32   out100
```

```
for (i in 0:length(df)) {
  newDf$rowOne <<- df$V(value of i)
}
```

I want to call `V1`, then `V2`, then `V3` etc... using the value of `i` so I can modify or use the content of the df data frame.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. your loop should start with index 1, not 0. And in the loop, you can access the respective column number directly through the index, e.g. `df[,i]`.

Comment: Thank you very much @deschen, that's exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know I needed a "," before the "i" inside of "[ ]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `paste()`, you can call your columns even if they aren't sorted. The idea is to paste the name "V" with the ith value of variable.

Here, you can loop over each column by just specifying the "i" value from the loop

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
     print(df[,paste("V",i,sep="")])
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner solution would be to loop through `colnames` like so:

```
iris

for (i in colnames(iris)){
  print(head(iris[i]))
}
```